# Zend 2 Index() is not available in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a project having lots of controller class files which do not contains **index()**. But If anyone type in address bar .../index then Zend show an error:
[image]

I don't need to create index() again an again in controller files. Can anyone suggest me here. What is the shortest way to fix this problem. 
Any help would be appriciable.

Comment: Somewhere exists an UserManagementController class with an indexAction method in it. As long as there is not called any other templat in this method you need an index template file in the secure/user-management/index folder.

Comment: @Marcel, Yes it exists in AbstractActionController class of Zend Library. Since my controller extends this therefore my controller has index() action. I don't want to create view files for each controller. I am looking for shortest solution.

Answer (score 0):

In completion of Marcel's comments You have either in a controller (maybe UserManagementController) :

- an indexAction.
- Or an Action wich define this index template.

You have more solution that can fix this issue.

- Using may terminate in route config to false, if it's what you want.
  No controller nor action will be call.
- Identify wich Action calls this template and fix it by returning the correct template or redirect to other action or return a notFoundAction.

Comment: Hi @Hoodi, thanks for your support. Yes it exists in AbstractActionController class of Zend Library. Since my controller extends this therefore my controller has index() action. I don't want to create view files for each controller, because i have lots of controller file. That's why looking for smart way so that i can return return a notFoundAction.

Comment: You should consider a view strategy then, or use the principal layout combined with a viewHelper